# How can I implement CSS transition effects with Tailwind when toggling the invisible property?

Tags: css-transitions, tailwind-css, tailwind-ui

I am using TailwindUI for a landing page, and it includes a drop down menu that, when uncollapsed, looks like this:

[image]

Right now, I make the menu appear when the "Solutions" link is clicked with some very simple in-line JavaScript that toggles the invisible property. The code looks something like this:

```
script.
  function closeMenu() {
    document.getElementById('buttonMenu').classList.toggle("invisible");
  }
```

I would like to know how I can implement transition effects that would make the toggling of the menu appear less abrupt. The following settings are recommended in by TailwindUI:

```
          //
            'Solutions' flyout menu, show/hide based on flyout menu state.
            Entering: "transition ease-out duration-200"
            From: "opacity-0 translate-y-1"
            To: "opacity-100 translate-y-0"
            Leaving: "transition ease-in duration-150"
            From: "opacity-100 translate-y-0"
            To: "opacity-0 translate-y-1"
```

What's the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: Your script assumes that the `invisible` CSS class isn't applied when it's clicked - that is a bad assumption to make. Instead of using `toggle` you should use `add` and `remove` to _ensure_ a CSS class name is set or not, instead of hoping that `classList`'s state is always correct.